# Sum IF VBA error '438' - object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, sumifs

I dont know why it gives me '438' - object doesn't support this property or method error, in the "Sumif" Function line.

How can I do the sumif function in VBA?

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("N2:N" & RSum), Range("C" & rw), Range("S2:S" & RSum))
```

And here's the whole code:

```
 Sub Macro1()
    Dim LR As Integer
    Dim rw As Integer
    Dim RSum As Integer

    LR = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    RSum = Range("n" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For rw = 2 To LR

            If Not IsEmpty(Range("C" & rw).Value) Then

            Range("G" & rw).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("N2:N" & RSum), Range("C" & rw), Range("S2:S" & RSum))

            End If

            If Range("G" & rw).Value = 0 Then
                Range("G" & rw).Value = "-"
                Range("F" & rw).Value = "No"
            ElseIf Range("G" & rw).Value <> 0 Then
                Range("F" & rw).Value = "Yes"

            End If
        Next rw
    End Sub
```

Excel Version 2002.

Comment: Try application.sumifs , often application.worksheetfunction doesn't work.

Comment: A lot has been updated since Excel 2002, I'd recommend using a newer version so in the future more people can help you because the majority of people have at least Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your second and third parameters are switched ?

2nd parameter sould be Range ***criteria_range1*** , and 3rd parameter should be ***criteria1***.

Try:

```
 Range("G" & rw).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("N2:N" & RSum), Range("S2:S" & RSum), Range("C" & rw))
```

Comment: I saw that right after i posted, fixted it but still gives me the same msg

Comment: @L.Fim please edit your original post with your updated code, because it still has that errors. this way other users will be able to look away from this and focus on other reasons

Comment: @L.Fim check my modified code and explanation above

Comment: Tryed it, still gives me the same msg. =/

Comment: GOT IT! its not 'sumifs'... its just 'sumif' and the order was right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This seems correct just you need to understand the criteria of Sumifs formula.
the order of Sumifs are-
1.Sum_range
2.Criteria_range
3.Criteria and so on.
So the correct syntax would be-

Range("G" & rw).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("N2:N" & RSum), Range("S2:S" & RSum), Range("C" & rw))

For more such questions you can check-
https://knowledgebase.techandmate.com

Thanks,